# getDrawingCache()にてNULLが返却される

Tags: android

http://qiita.com/satoshinew/items/a5fa3711d76429159dcb
↑のサイトに紹介されているカスタムビュークラスが使えるライブラリを入れあらかじめ用意された画像を読み込み回転や拡大をできるところまではいったのですが下のようにしてもbitmapが取れずnullになってしまいます。
どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

```
        gestureImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        gestureImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureImageView.getDrawingCache());
        Log.d("gestureImageView","="+bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キャプチャ部分のソースがどの箇所にはいっているかは上記からは読み取れませんが、
getDrawingCache()はonCreate()完了前ですと動作しません。
参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939664

また、ヒープが足りない場合もNULLを返します。
下記のポストではsize超過時のキャプチャ手段が記載されています。
参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116012

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
onCreate後にやっています。
サイズ超過時の方も試しましたが

Bitmap bitmapp =Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureImageView.getMeasuredWidth(), gestureImageView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
でエラーが出てしまいます
エラーはこれです
IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: エラーに関してはエラーメッセージの通りwidthかheightに0等を設定しているのだと思います。ということは対象のViewがmeasure前かなにかのタイミングなのではないでしょうか(onResume完了前など)。

Comment: 確認しましたが０を設定しているところが見当たらないです。
onClick時に処理をしているのですが駄目なのでしょうか?

Comment: ご提示のViewがどのようなタイミングでmeasureされているのかはわからないのでなんとも言えませんが、getwidth/getheight()を使っても値がとれませんでしょうか？https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: gestureImageViewはoncreateでmeasureしています。getwidt‌​h/getheight()これも試しましたところ両方とも0が返ってきます。

Comment: 宣言の仕方が間違っていたようです。回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: 問題が解決したのであれば、新規の質問をする前に✔マークを押し本質問を終了させてください。